# jquery and regexp for hide children elements

Tags: jquery

I have a simple div:

```
<div class="test">
    <div id="test1"></id>
    <div id="qwerqw"></id>
    ...
    <div id="23112"></id>
</div>
```

How to hide all elements in div ? $('.test').hide() hide only parent div.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use child selector of jquery as:
it will select the all the direct child of div.. select all direct of div with class `test` which are `<div>`

$('div.test > div').hide();

http://api.jquery.com/child-selector/

see this fiddle for example:
[jsfiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/niranjankala/M59JV/4/)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to hide the children, then you have to select them, either using the [*child selector* <sup>[docs]</sup>](http://api.jquery.com/child-selector/) or [`.children()` *<sup>[docs]</sup>*](http://api.jquery.com/children/).

Comment: Yes, this is way better and you don't need a regexp here.